# Multiple licenses in a single LICENSE file

Tags: licensing

Suppose I am releasing software under the A License. The software uses an external library licensed under the B license.

Can I put both licenses, A and B, together in a single file called LICENSE?

Comment: That depends on "B". If it allows it, yes you can.

Comment: @JCasso: what if B = GPLv2? :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot.

From GNU web site:

> If a library is released under the GPL (not the LGPL), does that mean
>   that any software which uses it has to be under the GPL or a
>   GPL-compatible license? (#IfLibraryIsGPL)
>
> Yes, because the software as it is actually run includes the library.
>
> *Source: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#IfLibraryIsGPL*

Libraries are usually released under **LGPL** instead of **GPL** because of this restriction. If you include a GPL'ed library, or even a piece of GPL'ed source code in your software, you will need to release your software under GPL.